# Webbrowser: Simulate mouse click programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, browser

Yes, I've searched in Internet for answer to my question, but haven't found anything helpful.
Please read to the end before you give me links to threads on "how to simulate mouse clicks".

I know how to find some element and call InvokeMember("click") on it. But! The problem is that the website I'm trying to automate detects automated tool and locks access. So there are some protections
from automating webbrowsing.

So, from said above the question is: How to simulate mouse click on some element in the page and thereby invoke all triggers associated with it?? As we click on it using mouse button all these triggers should work out.

I'm sorry for my English. Let me know if something is not clear in my question.

Comment: Erm, you're trying to do something that the web *explicitly* stops you from doing?  Talk to the site owner and work something out, that's the only reasonable way to have a lasting working relationship.  The alternate outcome is them simply blacklisting your IP.

Comment: there is no way to contact web site owner. They do not allow using of automating tools, only manual using is allowed. My question expects technical answer. For example, if we have to click on some button. How to determine which one onclick events and other javascript methods sohuld be called to simulate mouse click originally,

Comment: trying to automate clicking on your own google adwords are you?

Comment: No, you're wrong. There is nothing common with Google. It is another paid service, where I'm getting some sources. And website allows to grab data manually. After I grab it with my C# program it locks my login for some period. So, let's simplify my question: how to click on button and trigger all javascript methods assigned to this control? Is it enough to go upper the nested elements and clicking on them? As they also have onkeydown and onclick events.

Comment: How does the web site detects automated tools? We need more details to be able to give answers.

Comment: which service? why do they not want you to automate?

Answer (score 1):

Check out WatIn (http://watin.org/) that have extensive support for browser automation